# string to integer conversion in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a problem in String conversion here i pass a value through intent and access through bundle and now i want to convert into integer but it is showing force stopped ..........

MainActivity code:

```
             btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
         {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent in=new Intent(MainActivity.this,second.class);
            in.putExtra("id", "12");
            startActivity(in);
        }

    });
```

secondActivity code:

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    id=extras.getString("id");
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.value);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int myid=Integer.parseInt(id);
                            //tv.setText(myid);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), myid,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });

             LogCat:>
                 09-25 18:21:52.045: E/AndroidRuntime(1555): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                 09-25 18:21:52.045: E/AndroidRuntime(1555): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xc
                 09-25 18:21:52.045: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:230)
                 09-25 18:21:52.045: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:265)
                 09-25 18:21:52.045: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):    at com.example.convert.second$1.onClick(second.java:34)
                 09-25 18:21:52.045: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
                 09-25 18:21:52.045: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
                 09-25 18:21:52.045: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                 09-25 18:21:52.045: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                 09-25 18:21:52.045: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                  09-25 18:21:52.045: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                 09-25 18:21:52.045: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  09-25 18:21:52.045: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                   09-25 18:21:52.045: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                   09-25 18:21:52.045: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                   09-25 18:21:52.045: E/AndroidRuntime(1555):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: please post your logcat so we can see why it's crashing

Comment: @cyon: Not necessarily, it *could* be a field (static or instance doesn't matter). Though that'd be bad style IMO.

Comment: @user2816413: We still need the Logcat output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do `TextView.setText(int)`, do `TextView.setText(String)`, that means skipping the conversation completely. There are multiple inputs `setText()` can take, [as shown here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29).

What's happening in your case is that since you are converting your value over to an integer, you're inadvertently calling `public final void setText (int resid)` which assumes the integer  passed into it is the R.id value of something in your `strings.xml` file.

That's clearly not what you want to be doing, so you can do one of two things to fix it:

1. Replace your setText() with `setText("" + myid)`;
2. Stop converting your value to an int!